# File upload php

Tags: php, file-upload

I am working on how to file upload. Its kinda confusing for me due to I am just learning this. I have a database name `tblFile` for the uploads. I also have a folder on my desktop name upload for the `uploads`. Then I have a script called filename.php. Here is a little bit of my code that I have. As you can see I most likely got some areas wrong.The uploads are not going in the `uploads` folder.

```
$aryImages=array("image/jpeg","image/png");

$aryDocs=array("application/msword","application/pdf","video/x-msvideo");

$filename=filenameSafe($_FILES['upload']['name']);

$fileType=$_FILES["upload"]["type"];

if (in_array($_FILES["upload"]["type"],$aryImages)){
    createThumb($fileType,$_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name'],$filename,100,100);
}
elseif (in_array($_FILES["uploadFile"]["type"],$aryDocs)){
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name'],
              "/home/valerie2/public_html/elinkswap/filename.php/".$filename);

    $aryColumns=array(  "sessionID"=>$curSess,
                        "fileName"=>$filename,
                        "fileType"=>$fileType,
                        "thumbFileName"=>$thumbFilename,
                        "dateCreated"=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    dbInsert($filename,$aryColumns,$_FILES["upload"]["type"]);
}
else{
    echo "File Uploaded";
}
```

I am getting confused I have been cramping in php in all different areas into about 16 weeks and at this point everything just seems to be  run ons in my head. This is a part of homework but I think i have some files backwards and I am just hoping someone will help me understand what I am doing . Thanks

Edit:
Here is the file that I am working on more:

```
    <?php


function dbConnect(){
// Connect to the database:
 $hostname="localhost";
 $database="tblFile";
 $mysql_login="valerie2_shuawna";
 $mysql_password="norris";

 if(!($db=mysql_connect($hostname, $mysql_login, $mysql_password))){
    echo"error on connect";
 }
 else{
    if(!(mysql_select_db($database,$db))){
        echo mysql_error();
        echo "<br />error on database connection. Check your settings.";
    }
    else{
                echo "This is the home page. I have successfully made a connection to my database and everything
 is working as it should.";
        }


}

$aryImages=array("image/jpeg","image/png");
$aryDocs=array("application/msword","application/pdf","video/x-msvideo");
$filename=filenameSafe($_FILES['uploads']['name']);
$fileType=$_FILES["uploads"]["type"];
if (in_array($_FILES["uploads"]["type"],$aryImages)){
    createThumb($fileType,$_FILES['uploads']['tmp_name'],$filename,100,100);
}
elseif (in_array($_FILES["uploads"]["type"],$aryDocs)){
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploads']['tmp_name'],
"/home/valerie2/public_html/elinkswap/uploads/".$filename);
    $aryColumns=array("sessionID"=>$curSess,"fileName"=>$filename,"fileType"=>$fileType,"thumbFileName"=>$thumbFilename,"dateCreated"=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    dbInsert($filename,$aryColumns,$_FILES["upload"]["type"]);
}


    else{

    echo "File Uploaded";
  }
 }
function createThumb($type,$tmpname,$filename,$new_w,$new_h){
    $thumbFilename="tmb-".$filename;
    echo $type;
    echo "<br>".$tmpname;
    if (is_numeric(strpos($type,"jpeg"))){
        $src_img=imagecreatefromjpeg($tmpname);
    }
    if (is_numeric(strpos($type,"png"))){
        $src_img=imagecreatefrompng($tmpname);
    }
    $old_x=imageSX($src_img);
    $old_y=imageSY($src_img);
    if ($old_x > $old_y) {
        $thumb_w=$new_w;
        $thumb_h=$old_y*($new_h/$old_x);
    }
    if ($old_x < $old_y) {
        $thumb_w=$old_x*($new_w/$old_y);
        $thumb_h=$new_h;
    }
    if ($old_x == $old_y) {
        $thumb_w=$new_w;
        $thumb_h=$new_h;
    }
    $dst_img=imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_w,$thumb_h);
    imagecopyresampled($dst_img,$src_img,0,0,0,0,$thumb_w,$thumb_h,$old_x,$old_y);
    if (is_numeric(strpos($type,"jpeg"))){
        imagejpeg($dst_img,"/home/valerie2/public_html/elinkswap/uploads/".$thumbFilename);
        imagejpeg($src_img,"/home/valerie2/public_html/elinkswap/uploads/".$filename);
    }
    if (is_numeric(strpos($type,"png"))){
        imagepng($dst_img,"/home/valerie2/public_html/elinkswap/uploads/".$thumbFilename);
        imagepng($src_img,"/home/valerie2/public_html/elinkswap/uploads/".$filename);
    }
    imagedestroy($dst_img);
    imagedestroy($src_img);
    dbInsert($filename,$thumbFilename,$type);
}
function filenameSafe($filename) {
    $temp = $filename;
    // Lower case
    $temp = strtolower($temp);
    // Replace spaces with a ’_’
    $temp = str_replace(" ", "_", $temp);
    // Loop through string
    $result = "";
    for ($i=0; $i<strlen($temp); $i++) {
        if (preg_match('([0-9]|[a-z]|_|.)', $temp[$i])) {
            $result = $result.$temp[$i];
        }
    }
    dbConnect();
    $SQL="SELECT fileID FROM uploads WHERE fileName='".$result."'";
    //echo $SQL;
    $rs=mysql_query($SQL);
    echo mysql_num_rows($rs);
    if(mysql_num_rows($rs)!=0){
        $extension=strrchr($result,'.');
        $result=str_replace($extension,time(),$result);
        $result=$result.$extension;
    }
    return $result;
}

function dbInsert($filename,$thumbFilename,$type){
    dbConnect();
    $SQL="INSERT Into uploads (fileName,thumbFileName,fileType) values('".$filename."','".$thumbFilename."','".$type."')";
    //echo $SQL;
    mysql_query($SQL);


}



?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>File Upload</title>
<link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>


<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="filename.php" method="post">

Select File: <input type="file" name="uploads">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000"/>
<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="uploads">

</form>
```

But the files still dont load to the upload folder.

Comment: `/home/valerie2/public_html/elinkswap/filename.php/` - do you REALLY have a directory name "filename.php"? As well, you have ZERO checking if the upload succeeded, and are trusting the user will not rename "nastyvirus.exe" to "cutekittens.jpg" and bypass your (*ahem*) "security".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems your confusing the `$_FILES['upload']` and `$_FILES['uploadFile']` names. I ajust all to one name: `upload`. Let's see the code:

First some declarations...

```
$aryImages=array("image/jpeg","image/png");
$aryDocs=array("application/msword","application/pdf","video/x-msvideo");

$filename=filenameSafe($_FILES['upload']['name']);
$fileType=$_FILES["upload"]["type"];
```

Then I think you shoul verify the file type **BEFORE** you generate the `thumb`, right? Cause if file type isn't okay, you just don't create the `thumb`.

```
if (in_array($_FILES["upload"]["type"],$aryDocs)) {
```

So filetype is okay, now create the `thumb`...

```
    if (in_array($_FILES["upload"]["type"],$aryImages)) {
        createThumb($fileType,$_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'],$filename,100,100);
    }
```

Is heavy recommended to verify all steps like the `move_uploaded_file`. This function is crucial to the entire script works fine...

```
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'],
"/home/valerie2/public_html/elinkswap/filename.php/".$filename)) {
        $aryColumns=array("sessionID"=>$curSess,"fileName"=>$filename,"fileType"=>$fileType,"thumbFileName"=>$thumbFilename,"dateCreated"=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

Good, now here you verify if your function `dbInsert` do his job well...

```
        if (dbInsert($filename,$aryColumns,$_FILES["upload"]["type"])) {
           // Upload OK
        } else {
           // Error inserting on DB
        }
    } else {
        // Error moving file!!
    }
}
```

Note that I have not tested this script. I hope it helps!

Comment: All other anwsers have important tips!! See them all.

Comment: @sn1984: This is probably better than my answer. I highly recommend you read this post several times to ensure you understand it.

Comment: @Raskolnikov But what you said about `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and what Matthew said about `mime types` is important too!!

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that you are referring to both `$_FILES['upload']` and `$_FILES['uploadFile']`. I suspect that this is your issue. Check the name of the form field. If this does not solve your issue, I suggest reading the chapter on the PHP site about [file uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php). You may also find that you have not set up your form field correctly, for example by not setting up the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute in your `<form>` tag.

Also, you will get more debugging info by setting [error reporting](http://php.net/error_reporting) to a higher level. I suspect that this would have diagnosed your issue quicker than asking on stack overflow :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Raskolnikov wrote, also make sure your mime types cover all of what you need, for example "image/jpeg" is not the only mime type for JPG files, on some systems in can also be "image/jpg", and since the mime type is what the browser, ie) the end users machine is sending to your form, it can be one of many.

Check out http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/mime-types.shtml for a good list.